# Android open camera from button

Tags: android, android-camera

I hope this isn't a duplicate question but I am making an app that I want a button to open the camera app (the default android camera separately). How do I got about doing that? I know there is a function:

```
intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
```

Do I need to use that? And how do I call the button from the xml file?

Also do I need to worry about storing that picture or video or will the default camera app take care of that?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To call the camera you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivity(intent);
```

The image will be automatically saved in a default directory.

And you need to set the permission for the camera in your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"> </uses-permission>
```

Comment: I don't know about you but In my case it works without the permission

Comment: It is not necessary to include the CAMERA permission when you are launching the Image Capture action through an intent.

Answer (score 41):

```
 Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Button01);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
             startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
          Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
          ImageView imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); //sets imageview as the bitmap
          imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is camera_pic_request ?

Comment: @MuhammedFasil it is the request code you can pass the request code startActivityforResult and it will return the same code when the OnActivity result called. declare the code like this in your class `private static final int CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 1337;`

Comment: According to [this](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics), `data.getExtras().get("data")` will get you **only a thumbnail**!

Comment: @soshial You're right. `data.getExtras().get("data")` returns thumbnail and losing image quality...

Answer (score 7):

You can create a camera intent and call it as startActivityForResult(intent).

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

   // start the image capture Intent
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it is a bit late of a reply but you can use the below syntax as it worked with me just fine

```
Camera=(Button)findViewById(R.id.CameraID);
Camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent Intent3=new   Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
            startActivity(Intent3); 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

the below code does exactly what you want

```java
// use this intent on click event 

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent,CAMERA_REQUEST);`


// the above code is used in 'on activity Result'
    
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            image.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will set thumbnail version of the image captured by camera, and losing photo quality

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked perfectly fine .

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivity(intent);
```

and add this permission to mainfest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA">
```

It opens the camera,after capturing the image it saves the image to gallery with a new image set.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the action used in Intent but it's not the only thing you have to do. You'll also have to add

```
startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

To get it all done and retrieve the actual picture you could check the following thread.

[Android - Capture photo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491961/android-capture-photo)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a libray for pick image from camera or galley and cropping also

Try this,

ImagePro.Java

```
public class ImagePro
{
    public static String TAG = "ImagePro";
    Activity activity;
    Uri mImageCaptureUri;
    public static int CAMERA_CODE = 64;
    public static int GALLERY_CODE = 74;
    public static int CROPPING_CODE = 84;
    private final static int REQUEST_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE = 704;

    public ImagePro(Activity activity) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.outPutFile = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp.jpg");

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_REQ_CODE);
        }
    }

    private void LogToast(String message) {

        try {
            Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, message);
    }

    private void Toast(String message) {

        try {
            Toast.makeText(activity, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void Log(String message) {

        Log.d(TAG, message);
    }

    /**
     * This function return captured image path
     *
     * @param requestCode on activity result requestCode
     * @param resultCode on activity result resultCode
     * @param intent on activity result intent
     * @return ImageDetails values
     */
    public ImageDetails getImagePath(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        ImageDetails imageDetails = new ImageDetails();

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CODE) {
                imageDetails.setUri(mImageCaptureUri);
                imageDetails.setPath(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), mImageCaptureUri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LogToast(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                imageDetails.setBitmap(bitmap);
                imageDetails.setFile(new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath()));

            } else if(requestCode == GALLERY_CODE) {

                Uri uri = intent.getData();

                imageDetails.setUri(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = null;

                try {
                    bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity.getContentResolver(), uri);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    LogToast(e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                imageDetails.setBitmap(bitmap);
                imageDetails.setFile(new File(uri.getPath()));
                imageDetails.setPath(uri.getPath());

            } else if(requestCode == CROPPING_CODE) {
                try {
                    if(outPutFile.exists()){

                        imageDetails.setUri(Uri.fromFile(outPutFile));
                        imageDetails.setFile(outPutFile);
                        imageDetails.setPath(outPutFile.getPath());
                        Bitmap photo = decodeFile(outPutFile);
                        imageDetails.setBitmap(photo);
                    }
                    else {
                        LogToast("Error while save image");
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LogToast(e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        } else {
            LogToast("user cancelled.");
        }

        return imageDetails;
    }

    /**
     * Open image pick dialog.<br/>
     * CAMERA_CODE</br>
     * GALLERY_CODE
     */
    public void openImagePickOption() {

        final CharSequence[] items = { "Capture Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel" };

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                if (items[item].equals("Capture Photo")) {

                    captureImage();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {

                    pickImage();

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    /**
     * decode from file to bitmap
     * @param f file
     * @return Bitmap data
     */
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 512;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            Log(e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Capture image using camera <br/>
     * REQUEST_CODE = ImagePro.CAMERA_CODE
     */
    public void captureImage() {

        if(activity != null) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File f = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "temp1.jpg");
            mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageCaptureUri);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CODE);

        } else {

            LogToast("Activity not assigned");
        }
    }

    /**
     * pick image from gallery
     */
    public void pickImage() {

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        activity.startActivityForResult(i, GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * cropping the uri image
     * @param uri - open cropping dialog using the uri data
     */
    public void croppingImage(Uri uri) {

        CroppingIMG(uri);
    }

    int CROP_IMG_X=512;
    int CROP_IMG_Y=512;

    public void croppingImage(Uri uri, int cropX, int cropY) {

        CROP_IMG_X = cropX;
        CROP_IMG_Y = cropY;

        CroppingIMG(uri);
    }

    File outPutFile=null;

    private void CroppingIMG(Uri uri) {

        final ArrayList<CroppingOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<>();

        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");

        List<ResolveInfo> list = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
        int size = list.size();
        if (size == 0) {
            LogToast("Can't find image croping app");
        } else {
            intent.setData(uri);
            intent.putExtra("outputX", CROP_IMG_X);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", CROP_IMG_Y);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);

            //Create output file here
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(outPutFile));

            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i   = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));

                activity.startActivityForResult(i, CROPPING_CODE);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CroppingOption co = new CroppingOption();

                    co.title = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationLabel(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);
                    co.appIntent.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropingOptionAdapter adapter = new CropingOptionAdapter(activity.getApplicationContext(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                builder.setTitle("Choose Cropping App");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                builder.setAdapter( adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                        activity.startActivityForResult( cropOptions.get(item).appIntent, CROPPING_CODE);
                    }
                });

                builder.setOnCancelListener( new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel( DialogInterface dialog ) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null ) {
                            activity.getContentResolver().delete(mImageCaptureUri, null, null );
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                } );

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Capture image using camera<br/>
     * REQUEST_CODE = User defined code<br/>
     * <br/>
     * @param iRequestCode User defined code
     */
    public void captureImage(int iRequestCode) {

        CAMERA_CODE = iRequestCode;
        captureImage();
    }

    /**
     * get path, bitmap, file and uri from image details object
     */
    public class ImageDetails {

        String path="";
        Bitmap bitmap=null;
        File file=null;
        Uri uri=null;

        public Uri getUri() {
            return uri;
        }

        public void setUri(Uri uri) {
            this.uri = uri;
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }

        public void setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
        }

        public Bitmap getBitmap() {
            return bitmap;
        }

        public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
            this.bitmap = bitmap;
        }

        public File getFile() {
            return file;
        }

        public void setFile(File file) {
            this.file = file;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Created by DP on 7/12/2016.
     */
    public class CroppingOption {
        public CharSequence title;
        public Drawable icon;
        public Intent appIntent;
    }

    public class CropingOptionAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
        private ArrayList<CroppingOption> mOptions;
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public CropingOptionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CroppingOption> options) {

            super(context, R.layout.croping_selector, options);
            mOptions  = options;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup group) {
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.croping_selector, null);

            CroppingOption item = mOptions.get(position);

            if (item != null) {
                ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_icon)).setImageDrawable(item.icon);
                ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_name)).setText(item.title);

                return convertView;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
ImagePro imagePro;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imagePro = new ImagePro(this);
    }

    public void onClickUploadImageButton(View view) {

        imagePro.openImagePickOption();
    }
```

onActivityResult

```
if(requestCode == CAMERA_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            imageDetails = imagePro.getImagePath(CAMERA_CODE, RESULT_OK, data);
            ivCrop.setImageBitmap(imageDetails.getBitmap());
//imageDetails.getPath(), imageDetails.getBitmap(), imageDetails.getUri(), imageDetails.getFile
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
pic = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
mApp.getPreference().getString(Common.u_id, "") + ".jpg");
picUri = Uri.fromFile(pic);
cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, picUri);
cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, PHOTO);
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
public class camera_act extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_act);
         ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image);
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent,90);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
       Bitmap bitmap = data.getExtras.get("imageKey");
       imageView.setBitmapImage(bitmap);
            
        }
    }
}
```