# startActivityForResult return data null

Tags: android, camera, startactivityforresult

I try to **send image from camera** to my activity. I call `startActivityForResult` from `adapter` like this :

```
photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        mActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(part.getId());
    }
});
```

Here's that method on Activity :

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(String id) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File

        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    "com.example.eltegps011.eltegps.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("Id",id);

            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 2) {
        part = (Part) data.getSerializableExtra("Part");
        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: ");

}if(requestCode == 1313) {
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data");
    String id = data.getStringExtra("Id");
    Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + id);
}
```

However, `Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap)data.getExtras().get("data")` is `null` and **resultCode is always -1**. It looks like intent doesn't get to `activity`. Any idea why ?

Comment: follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13977619/5296734) it may help you find the solution.

Comment: `// Error occurred while creating the File`.And you still continu as if nothing happened. You should display a toast saying so and return.

Comment: `photoFile = createImageFile()`. There is no need to create that file other than checking if the directory is writable. You can directly delete it. Leave creation to the camera app.

Comment: thanks greenapps , it works. However, I've got one more problem :) When I set extras like this :  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra("Id",id);  only photo is correct, id return null. Do you know why ?

Comment: any solution to this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Full Demo working on all versions.**

For both Capture and pick image

Note: Android 6.0 get runtime permissions on click then procced.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView camera, gallery;
    File photoFile;
    Uri uri;
    private final static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private final static int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        camera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Img);
        gallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();

            }
        });
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            photoFile = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory("/myimage/save.jpg");
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            uri = data.getData();
            String selecteadImage = getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            if (data != null && data.getData() != null) {
                String selecteadImage = getRealPathFromURI(this, data.getData());
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    String selecteadImage = photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Image path " + selecteadImage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Manifest Permissions:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**activity_main:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/image_1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```