# camera app crashes after i click the image

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera

I am creating an android which when started launches the camera and when I click the image a popup is launched which shows the image I clicked. Popup has three buttons save,reload and cancel. App is crashing when I click the image.

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    public static final String ALLOW_KEY = "ALLOWED";
    public static final String CAMERA_PREF = "camera_pref";
    Button Close;
    Button reload;
    ImageView imageView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        openCamera();


    }
    private void openCamera() {//i open the camera here
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);

        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,  Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
                initiatepopupwindow()
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
            }
        }
    private PopupWindow pwindo;

    private void initiatePopupWindow() { 

       LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup));
         imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        try {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 700, 770, true);
                    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                }
            }, 100);


            Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            Button reload = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            close.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View popupView) {
                    pwindo.dismiss();
                }
            });
            reload.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View popupView) {
                    openCamera();
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Logs**

```
01-03 13:25:23.061 22093-22093/com.example.shivadeeps.aapam_auto    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.example.shivadeeps.aapam_auto, PID: 22093
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data dat=content://media/external/images/media/165 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.shivadeeps.aapam_auto/com.example.shivadeeps.aapam_auto.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4756)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4799)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:211)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1754)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at com.example.shivadeeps.aapam_auto.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6833)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4752)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:4799) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:211) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1754) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

activity main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shivadeeps.aapam_auto.MainActivity">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

layout of popup

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
android:id="@+id/popup">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/save"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/reload"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</Button>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="77dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/error"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
</Button>




<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Please Post logcat?

Comment: if anyone has an alternative program please post

Comment: I think you didn't see the first comment? Post the logcat we will try to help you to fix the issue yourself

Comment: i posted the logcat

Comment: Bitmap your getting is null

Comment: how do i fix it

Comment: are you sure you have `imageView1` in your xml file?

Comment: yes.i have been stuck three days with this

Comment: Bitmap is null! you may try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13977245/android-open-camera-from-button)

Comment: if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) { } use this one and please show your activity_main xml.

Comment: Post activity_main.xml

Comment: i have posted activity main and layout of popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

**imageView1** is **not in activity_main** layout file **its in popup.xml** layout file

So its unable to initialize imageView and throwing NLE.

Move

```
imageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

from onCreate to

```
private void initiatePopupWindow() { 
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout,
            (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.popup));
imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);  //add this line

 ...//your code


}
```

Comment: @phoenixshiv  u didn't update ur code properly its not this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); its layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1); Check my answer once

Comment: yeah  i changed that and it is working.thank you so much for your help

Comment: @phoenixshiv Glad! that helped:)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is in popup method you are inflating other layout and taking imageview wrong way.

`this.findViewById` will try to get imageview from contentview which is set to activity not from popup view
so take image view from popupview

```
layout

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/popup"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/save"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/reload"></Button>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="77dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/error"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete"></ImageView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Activity Code Change

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        initiatePopupWindow();
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } else {
            Log.e("ImageView", "Popup imageview NULL");
        }
    }

    private PopupWindow pwindo;
    private ImageView imageView;

    private void initiatePopupWindow() {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test, null);
        imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        android.os.Handler handler = new android.os.Handler();
        try {
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    pwindo = new PopupWindow(layout, 700, 770, true);
                    pwindo.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                }
            }, 100);


            Button close = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button3);
            Button reload = (Button) layout.findViewById(R.id.button2);

            close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View popupView) {
                    pwindo.dismiss();
                }
            });
            reload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View popupView) {
                    openCamera();
                }
            });


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: you my friend are a godsend.It is working.Thank you so much for your help