# Can a sprite image be displayed on the phone's camera?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, sprite

I want to create an app for Android that will be able to access the phone's camera. I know this is possible so that's not a problem. The [android developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) website gives plenty of information on that. 
I was wondering is it possible, when i open the camera through my app, can an image (such as a sprite image from a game) be displayed on the screen?
so when i take the picture the sprite character is also in the picture.
The sprite needs to be on the screen when I open the camera, and that image needs to be saved

Hopefully I've explained what I am trying to do because I can't find any information on this

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491961/android-capture-photo

Comment: Check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Comment: thanks for the links but they didn't really help. I know how to access the camera from my app, but how do I get the sprite image to display on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display camera preview on SurfaceView, or as a SurfaceTexture in OpenGL. The latter approach lets you add any 3D sophistication to your display, but even a simple SurfaceView may be overlayed by an ImageView, even simply in the **layout.xml**, e.g.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@null"
                android:windowNoTitle="true">


<SurfaceView 
    android:id="@+id/preview"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sprite"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/sprite" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelaiveLayout>
```

You can use an ImageView with transparent background, and a PNG with transparency to display a sprite of exotic shape.